# Выброс двух случайных ограниченных чисел

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, как выглядит код на PHP, в котором задано, что число a и число b больше или равно одного но меньше или равно 100. Нужно чтобы скрипт генерировал случайные  эти числа, а при перезагрузке страницы опять генерировал новые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php есть функция [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).
Использовать так

```
a = rand(1,100);
b = rand(1,100);
echo("a = ".a." b = ".b);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ТУТ все подробно](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)